# Backend listing grid view page not opening order listing cms page & block listing etc

Tags: javascript, cms-block, cms-pages, magento2.2.7, listing

Backend listing grid view page not opening order listing cms page & block listing etc.. Admin panel not able to load multiselect.html, text.html, html.html, actions.html and js file as per console log. [image: t]

Comment: run Magento commands `setup:upgrade` then redeploy static content files

Comment: ok i am running the command

Comment: still showing spinner loading loading.

Comment: do you have custom module?

Comment: yes i have custom module

Comment: you can disable first custom modules and check if the issue still exists.

Comment: disabled the module coming same error as per image

Comment: before this error i have added script in cms block page..